# When choosing a modifier, is there any difference between using a noun and its adjectival counterpart?

Tags: word-choice

When choosing a modifier, is there any difference between using a noun and its adjectival counterpart? For example (but not limited to)

> **journalism** standards

and

> **journalistic** standards

Comment: I think it definitely depends on the specific pair of words. In this case, "journalism standards" is incorrect for me. You may find cases where both are valid, but even if the meanings are very close, there will always be a slight difference (in register/formality, in semantic associations, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an adjective form, we usually prefer that; the noun-adjunct form is mostly used when there is no adjective form available.

As with any general rule in English, though, there are always exceptions. I don’t see one with this specific example, but it’s possible someone in the field of journalism might see a slight difference in meaning between the two forms and thus have a preference for one or the other depending on exactly what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

That depends very much on the specific noun/adjective pair, and the context. In some cases the change of meaning will be very small, if there is an change. In other cases the change will be large, or one form will be incorrect or unnatural.

Here the noun phrase "journalism standards" is in my view a bit unusual. Using "standards of journalism" or  "journalistic standards": would be more common. But without context I cannot judge precisely.